# Angular cli command 'ng serve' print multiple lines instead a single line log

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

when i run an angular project with ng serve, it prints every single operation when it is building modules. It runs the server well, but it is not supposed to work this way, but like a single line log. Someone knows how to fix it?

- `Angular CLI: 1.5.0`
- `Node: 6.12.2`
- `OS: Ubuntu 16.04 x64`
- `Angular: 5.1.`

Comment: It's not works means?

Comment: try running it on the prod environment

Comment: In other pc's it shows just a single line updating for each operation, but in mine it is like 269 messages printed for every module compilation. I don't know if it is something bad with my OS... NodeJS works well as a single line log when it install dependencies.

Comment: I have the same problem, didn't find the solution, in every chance of progress the ng serve emmits another line in the console, and it doesn't change the current line